# Bucket explained (not sort)

Tags: data-structures

I need clarification on a bucket.  I was taught that a bucket was a collection of ordered values that mark the presence of a value, or the count of a value.  It is most often implemented using an array (boolean, int, or any object type).

As I am brushing up for a job interview I keep coming back to instances online that seem to say that a particular value in an array is itself a bucket, rather than the entire array being the bucket.  Can someone please clarify.  As always I searched previous questions and found none.

Thanks

Comment: Honestly I'd be surprised if I ever encountered an interviewer who knew this, or even cared. I know I don't!

Comment: you don't care or you don't know?  My neurosis would appreciate it:)

Comment: Both. I know arrays inside and out, but "buckets"? Never had any use for it, probably never will. Maybe that's a privilege I get for working in higher-level languages, who knows? I don't!

Comment: I just don't want to get caught using the wrong, or perceived to be wrong, language.  Is the array the bucket or the index?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you mean buckets in a hash table.

A hash table often is implemented as an array of buckets (which are arrays or linked lists, too). The buckets typically hold the elements themselves. I don't see a need for sorting a bucket because hash values can be duplicates (hash collision) and you'd have to partly iterate over them anyway.
Also, in the ideal case a bucket only contains one element.

---

The description of `std::unordered_map::bucket_size` implies that a bucket can contain multiple values.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/bucket_size/:

> `size_type bucket_size ( size_type n ) const;`
>
> Returns the number of elements in bucket n.
>
> A bucket is a slot in the container's internal hash table to which
>   elements are assigned based on the hash value of their key.
>
> The number of elements in a bucket influences the time it takes to
>   access a particular element in the bucket.

Comment: Thank You.  I guess now the answer is that a DS or container can contain a bucket/s, and buckets themselves can have size 1 to n.

Comment: This is my understanding. Never heard of a datastructure called Bucket that stands on its own. Also, the article on Wikipedia is very vague. If such a DS exists, I agree with Niet, it's unlikely you will be asked about it. However: Any explanation of Hashtables that doesn't mention Buckets is incomplete IMO.